# UnicodeDecodeError using TextBlob and Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, textblob

**Issue Resolved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150205/python-2-7-and-textblob-typeerror-the-text-argument-passed-to-init-tex)**I am using a Windows 10 PC and trying to scrape and analyze a website forum.  My solution uses Scrapy and Textblob, and I'm running Python 2.7.  The scraping generates the desired output (which I save as either a .csv or .json).  However, when I use this file in the Python script that integrates TextBlob, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcus\Documents\Blog\Python\Scripts\Brooks\textblob_sentiment.py", line 14, in <module>
print blob
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\compat.py", line 30, in <lambda>
cls.__str__ = lambda x: x.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 425: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Script that generates this error is:

```
# from __future__ import division, unicode_literals (This was recommended     for Python 2.x, but didn't help in my case.)

import csv

from textblob import TextBlob


infile = 'items.csv'

with open(infile, 'r') as scrape_file:
    comments = csv.reader(scrape_file)
    for comment in comments:
        sentence = comment[0]
        blob = TextBlob(sentence)
        print blob
```

Structure of the code is similar to another thread I found on SO, and I have also tried to integrate encode/decode methods into this script based on other threads I found on SO.  But perhaps I didn't do so properly  (I am not a developer).  I also tried to open the json file, thinking perhaps the problem was the way that the .csv was encoded.
I can print the desired content (e.g., "print sentence" or "print comments", it is only when I try to use TextBlob that I receive the error.
Might you have a solution that unblocks this error?
And since I'd like to use these libraries again, how can I avoid similar headaches?

thanks so much for your help on this...

Comment: That looks like a bug in the library.

Comment: try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line of that file.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately that didn't seem to help.  One additional note:  The error message gets thrown after providing some of the desired output, so it seems like there's something specific in the output that is causing the error for TextBlob.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', sentence).encode('ascii','ignore').lower()
```

make sure to import unicode

```
import unicodedata
```

Comment: Thanks Omair,  when I add both lines, I get "No module named unicode".  if from the command line I then do "pip install unicode" I get "No matching distribution found for unicode".  I found a library that Python seems to understand called "unicodedata".  When I imported that in my script, and included your suggested unicodedata.normalize line (between the lines beginning with "sentence" and "blob", the error is "TypeError: must be unicode, not str."

Comment: Thanks, I still received errors (same unicodedecode error, Textblob requiring unicode and receiving a list etc).  I have refactored my code and while my fundamental issue with Textblob is unresolved, my error is different and it probably merits a different subject line, so I will open a different question.

Comment: Thanks again @Omair.  Please see my edit in the OP for a link to the eventual resolution.