# Python 2.7 and Textblob - TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <type 'list'>

Tags: python-2.7, csv, textblob

**Update:  Issue resolved.** (see comment section below.)  Ultimately, the following two lines were required to transform my .csv to unicode and utilize TextBlob: row = [cell.decode('utf-8') for cell in row], and text = ' '.join(row).

Original question:
I am trying to use a Python library called Textblob to analyze text from a .csv file.  Error I receive when I call Textblob in my code is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Marcus\Documents\Blog\Python\Scripts\Brooks\textblob_sentiment.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       blob = TextBlob(row)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 344, in
>   **init**
>       'must be a string, not {0}'.format(type(text)))TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not

My code is:

```
#from __future__ import division, unicode_literals #(This was recommended for Python 2.x, but didn't help in my case.)

#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
from textblob import TextBlob
with open(u'items.csv', 'rb') as scrape_file:
reader = csv.reader(scrape_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    row = [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
    print row
    blob = TextBlob(row)
    print type(blob)
```

I have been working through UTF/unicode issues.  I'd originally had a different subject which I posed to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Python%202.7%20and%20Textblob%20-%20TypeError%3A%20The%20%60text%60%20argument%20passed%20to%20%60__init__(text)%60%20must%20be%20a%20string%2C%20not%20%3Ctype%20%27list%27%3E). (Since my code and the error have changed, I'm posting to a new thread.) Print statements indicate that the variable "row" is of type=str, which I thought indicated that the reader object had been transformed as required by Textblob. The source .csv file is saved as UTF-8.  Can anyone provide feedback as to how I can get unblocked on this, and the flaws in my code?
Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe you can make change as below:

```
row = str([cell.encode('utf-8') for cell in row])
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Unfortunately when I replace my previous "row = " line with the one you suggest above, I get the dreaded Unicodedecode error that I was getting with previous versions of my code.  That error is:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 425: ordinal not in range(128).  I'm not sure what else to do, as even scrubbing my source file won't help me the next time I regenerate it.

Comment: @Marcus Hi Marcus, could you tell me which encoding you are using for your terminal?

Comment: I am on a Windows 10 PC.  The source .csv file ('items.csv') is generated from the command line using the following command:  scrapy crawl newrun -o items.csv.  Then I have tried to check/change the encoding by opening items.csv in notepad++.  I hope this gives you a better sense...

Comment: @Marcus Hmmm, please try one last thing. To change cell.encode('utf-8') to cell.decode('utf-8'). Also, remove that str(). So it should be row=[cell.decode('utf-8') for cell in row]. If that does not work, then I'm afraid I am out of ideas. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks again for your help.  I made your suggested edit, and I am getting some content to flow, but then the script errors out at "for row in reader".  error message says: "Error: field larger than field limit (131072).  I also commented out your line and tested with my original line, and I get the same error message at the same spot in my source file.  I haven't seen that error before - any ideas?

Comment: @Marcus Could you show me how your csv file looks like? It looks like it contains huge amount of fields.

Comment: @Marcus Could you show me how your csv file looks like? It looks like it contains huge amount of fields. Try this: import sys and  then add a line underneath: csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

Comment: I am unblocked :-).  Field limit issue was resolved by re-running my scraper, which addressed whatever corruption had been in my source file.  After that, it appeared that even with your suggested cell.decode line, the "row" was still a list.  so I added a Join statement.  That finally got me to unicode text and now I can access TextBlob.  I will update above and Accept your answer.  thanks again.

Comment: @Marcus Congrat! Glad to hear this!