# Apply method in Pandas can not handle a function

Tags: python, pandas, textblob

I am new to pandas. The following is a sub_set of a dataframe named news:
Id is the id of news and the text column includes the news:

```
Id             text
1              the news is really bad.
2              I do not have any courses.
3              Asthma is very prevalent.
4              depression causes disability.
```

I am going to calculate sentiment for each news in the "text" column.
I need to create a column to include the result of sentiment analysis.

This is my code:

```
    from textblob import TextBlob
    review = TextBlob(news.loc[0,'text'])
    print (review.sentiment.polarity)
```

This code works for just one of the news in the text column.

I also wrote this function:

```
    def detect_sentiment(text):

        blob = TextBlob(text)
        return blob.sentiment.polarity

news['sentiment'] = news.text.apply(detect_sentiment)
```

But it has the following error:

```
The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'float'>
```

Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150205/python-2-7-and-textblob-typeerror-the-text-argument-passed-to-init-tex

Comment: Your code works fine when I launch it. What version of python/pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using python version 3.7

Comment: Try ```news.dtypes```.  If text is listed as ```object```, you may have non-strings mixed into your news.text series.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your bug: your exact code is working perfectly fine to me using `pandas==0.24.2` and `Python 3.4.3`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

news = pd.DataFrame(["the news is really bad.",
                   "I do not have any courses.",
                   "Asthma is very prevalent.",
                   "depression causes disability."], columns=["text"])

def detect_sentiment(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    return blob.sentiment.polarity

news['sentiment'] = news.text.apply(detect_sentiment)

display(news)
```

Result:

```py
+----+-------------------------------+-------------+
|    | text                          |   sentiment |
|----+-------------------------------+-------------|
|  0 | the news is really bad.       |        -0.7 |
|  1 | I do not have any courses.    |         0   |
|  2 | Asthma is very prevalent.     |         0.2 |
|  3 | depression causes disability. |         0   |
+----+-------------------------------+-------------+
```